# An asynchronous operation exceeded the page timeout (trying to use HttpRequestMessage with ASP.NET WebForms page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have created a web API in AWS that I am trying to get some JSON back from using a web page built in ASP.NET Webforms (most up-to-date version). I can't get the asynchronous part to work. Either the GET method hangs seemingly forever, or - following the best practice approach from the Microsoft documentation - I get this error after a little while:

> [TimeoutException: An asynchronous operation exceeded the page
>   timeout.]    System.Web.UI.d__554.MoveNext() +984

I know this is something to do with the wait/async portion of the code and being in ASP.NET because of the following.

- If I use very similar code in a console application it works fine.
- If i call the web API using POSTMAN it works fine.

I have made async = true in the page directive. Here is my page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetStuffAsync));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        renderStoreCards.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here is my method

```
    private async Task GetStuffAsync()
    {
        string testHtml = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var signer = new AWS4RequestSigner("AccessKey", "SecretKey");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://some-aws-address-changed-for-stack-overflow.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/tables/InSiteStoreInformation/ServerName")
            };

            request = await signer.Sign(request, "execute-api", "ap-southeast-2");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            renderStoreCards.Text = ex.Message; 
        }
    }
```

The above example produces a TimeoutException. Previous to the above, I was trying the following code. This works fine in a console app, but not in the ASP.NET page.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MainAsync().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception occured {ex.Message}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var signer = new AWS4RequestSigner("AccessKey", "SecretKey");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://<Hiddenforstackoverflowpost>.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/tables/InSiteStoreInformation/ServerName")
                };

                request = await signer.Sign(request, "execute-api", "ap-southeast-2");

                var client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic sales = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseStr);
                Console.WriteLine($"Server = {sales[0].ServerName}");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Write(responseStr);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am by no means an expert in async/wait combinations, but it appears that the HttpClient I'm using has no synchronous alternative, so I have to figure this out.

Comment: I should point out that I have been banging my head against a brick wall all day. I simply cannot get this to work. It's frustrating, because I spent a bulk of my time setting up a really good web API that I can call using path parameters etc, but my whole plan hinged on providing a lightweight ASP.NET Webforms front end that would just consume the Web API, get the JSON and render the page based on that JSON data. I can't figure out why I can't use HttpRequestMessage the same as I have in the console app 'test'.

Comment: Not sure what your `RegisterAsyncTask` does with the `getAsync()`, but since it's hanging seemingly forever it could have something to do with the deadlock described [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). If the `GetAsync()` will be called immediately anyway on `Page_Load`, you could just try making the event method async and awaiting the `getAsync()`.

Comment: Have you tried using something like Fiddler to see what's going on the wire?

Comment: Hi Paulo, I did try Fiddler, it shows a status 200 call to the URL, but I can confirm it never reaches the web API, as it has logging which records when it's called, and nothing ever fires. I will try Fiddler again and provide the output in my question.  And Michael, I have read a lot about deadlock scenarios, and have tried a few different ways, none seem to work. I *think* I may have already tried what you're suggesting, but I will do it specifically and again update my question with the code I try if it doesn't work.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of using httprequwst essage to a web api from an asp.net Page they can show me? One that is working and that in theory I could use (so if it doesn’t work, I know it’s not the code as such, and may be environment or something). I’m at a loss here but I have to get this working

Comment: @JamesMatson The request code seems alright (`GetStuffAsync()`). The only thing i would change is putting the `HttpClient` in a using `using` statement (to make sure it gets disposed after use) and making a proper JsonObject to deserialize the response string. These things won't help with the problem you described though. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @JamesMatson Tried to search a little. Unfortunately i am not that familiar with asp.net but maybe you have to mark the page as async (`<%@ Page Title="Async" Language="C#" CodeBehind="Async.aspx.cs" Inherits="Whatever" Async="true" %>
`) like this [blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) suggests. Or try giving `new PageAsyncTask` an async delegate like in this [article](https://codewala.net/2014/03/28/writing-asynchronous-web-pages-with-asp-net-part-3/).

Comment: e.g. `new PageAsyncTask(async () =>
            {
                await GetStuffAsync();
            })`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across.
The timeouts are most likely caused by ReadAsStringAsync as you neglected to use '.ConfigureAwait(false)' on it. Running async tasks inside ASP.net can be very finicky especially around execution contexts. It most likely is some kind of dead-lock on the async method when it tries to restore the execution context on its return. This usually fails due to the nature of IIS hosting. I am not sure if it actually is a dead-lock or some other issue under the hood. Just make sure to always use .ConfigureAwait(false).

I know this is old, but maybe it helps someone else coming across this issue.